# Excel VBA Networkdays with Company Holidays, Unable to get Networkdays Property

Tags: excel, vba

in my Macro I calculate the networkdays between two dates, but it should also include the company holidays.

So for my code:

```
With MasterWB.Worksheets("Company Holidays")
    .Activate
    Holidaylist = .Range("H:H").Value
End With

If (Application.WorksheetFunction.NetworkDays(date1, date2, Holidaylist) > 14) Then
 'do something
End If
```

Error shows that it cant get the worksheetfunction property, but can not figure out why. The docs shows it should be possible with given range of cells which contains the company holidays.

**EDIT**

date1 and date2 are normal date values, eg. `date`(today) and `2019/09/19`
Holidaylist is a range in my worksheet containing datevalues like

```
2019/8/10
2019/8/11
2019/8/12
```

Comment: What are `date1` and `date2` and the data in `HolidayList`? No repro with the provided info. Does that column H only contain dates?

Comment: mb, edited example dates and yes Column H only contains date values

Comment: Trying to narrow this down - does it error if you remove `Holidaylist` temporarily? Is it possible that you have text that looks like dates in that column?

Comment: Thanks I found my mistake! Theres was indeed a value which wasnt a date value in H!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that the third parameter contains other data, for example a Header Row, like (Holiday Dates). You should give in a narrower range, e.g. B2:B10 if you know the exact place of the holiday dates.

If you don't know or it can change, then you can use the .End and .Resize functions to determine the Range. Let us assume that you have "Holiday Dates" in B1, the first actual date is in B2, and all other dates are in consecutive rows below it. In this case you should use the following to set the Holidaylist:

```
Holidaylist = .Range(.Range("B2"), .Range("B1").End(xlDown)).Value
```